# How to resolve date parsing error in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, date, parsing, datatables, laravel-8

I'm using **Laravel v8.65**, and **MSSQL** as a database.

I have a table *human_resources* with one of the columns as `dob` with datatype `date`

So my records in that column looks like `2010-05-05`

When I use cast as below, I get error while displaying the table content in a grid

```
protected $casts = [    
        'dob' => 'date:d-M-Y',
    ];
```

The error I get is

[image]

I'm using datatables to display the records.

My colleagues who are on the same branch and have the same code do not face this issue.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: If the people you work with don't have the issue, then either your data is different or you need to do a composer or npm install or npm run dev.

Comment: Data is similar since we all point to one common database, and I ran composer and npm install, issue still persists

Comment: Did you set the locale of your browser different from your colleagues?

Comment: Not sure what the issue was, but resolved it by changing the type to timestamp instead of date